# Am i making the correct use of margins in my bootstrap navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Everything looks great or at least the way I want it to. But it feels like i am making incorrect use of the margins to achieve this look. Is this the best way or is there a more intuitive solution?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubZR7.jpg

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
      <h1>HHHHH HHHH</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
      <nav id="nav">                          
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="services.php">Services</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <a href="Request.php">Request service</a>              
      </nav>
    </div><!--/#HEADER-->
```

Css

```
 .navbar-header>h1{
            float:left;
            margin:10px 414px 0px 20px;
            font-size: 38px;    
            color:#ffe;
            transition: all 0.3s ;
        }

        .navbar-header>h1:hover{
            color:#4EB1BA;
        }

        #nav{
            margin-top: 30px;
        }


        #nav>a{ 
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left:30px;
            margin:51px 0px 30px 30px;
            color:#E9E9E9;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        #nav>a:hover{
            color:#4eb1ba;  
        }
```

Comment: Probably more well suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have a few suggestions that could help to clean up the code a bit more. May make for cleaner coding in the future.

I see how you have applied `margin:10px 414px 0px 20px;` to your `<h1>` tag. I would suggest that you change this to `margin:10px 0 0 20px;` and simply add in a `float:right` to your `#nav` ID on the page. This will allow for the heading to be changed if needed to or a new font to be applied to it and not have this effect the position of your nav section. All you need to do then is change the margin you have for your nar to `#nav { margin:30px 20px 0; }`.

Also maybe for future you can use the `<header></header>` tags instead of a `id="header"`. works the same way really but just cleaner code again.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: No worries happy to. Any other code questions i may be able to help with just ask that's what we are here for.